# Book Recommendations on Numerical Analysis for Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

I am looking for a rather advanced textbook that covers numerical schemes for multi-dimensional partial differential equations. Hoping that someone knows a good reference with partially worked examples/solution checks. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Langtangen & Linge _'Finite Difference Computing with PDEs; A Modern Approach'_, Boyds _'Chebyshev and Fourier Spectral Methods'_, Gottlieb _'Spectral Methods for Time Dependent Problems'_ and Leveques _'Finite Difference Methods for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations'_. You can find most of these online for free.